# JSON Parsing numeric data in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{
  "353701094714280": {
    "dt_server": "2021-09-19 02:24:26",
    "dt_tracker": "2021-09-17 9:57:56",
    "lat": "1.059998",
    "lng": "104.134",
    "altitude": "0",
    "angle": "0",
    "speed": "0",
    "params": {
      "pump": "0",
      "track": "1",
      "bats": "1",
      "acc": "0",
      "batl": "6"
    },
    "loc_valid": "1"
  }
}
```

I need to get data speed from JSON. I am using this code, but i am stuck.

`$json->speed;`

Comment: >ou are looking for json_decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your speed data is stored in key "353701094714280", so :

```
$json_buffer = '{"353701094714280":{"dt_server":"2021-09-19 02:24:26","dt_tracker":"2021-09-17 9:57:56","lat":"1.059998","lng":"104.134","altitude":"0","angle":"0","speed":"0","params":{"pump":"0","track":"1","bats":"1","acc":"0","batl":"6"},"loc_valid":"1"}}';

$data = json_decode($json_buffer);
echo $data->{'353701094714280'}->speed;
```

If you don't know the key, you can force json_decode() result to be an associative array instead of an object with `json_decode($json_buffer, true)` and use foreach() or array_key_first() :

```
$json_buffer = '{"353701094714280":{"dt_server":"2021-09-19 02:24:26","dt_tracker":"2021-09-17 9:57:56","lat":"1.059998","lng":"104.134","altitude":"0","angle":"0","speed":"0","params":{"pump":"0","track":"1","bats":"1","acc":"0","batl":"6"},"loc_valid":"1"}}';

$data = json_decode($json_buffer, true);
$first_key = array_key_first($data);
echo $data[$first_key]['speed'];
```

http://php.net/json-decode
http://php.net/array-key-first